# websql phonegap app: database upgrade

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, web-sql

I'm upgrading my android/phonegap app in the google market store.

Due to an oversight on my part, I need to start again and will need to delete existing user data stored in websql and start again capturing it in the correct format.

What's the best way to do this to ensure the data is deleted the first time the app is upgraded on the users phone and doesn't do it each time the app is launched?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write your SQL code so that it will drop the table that the user information is stored in if that table exists. Then store you user info in a new, different name, table. For example:

```
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NEW_DEMO (id unique, data)');
```

Comment: hmmm that's going to require many changes i.e. renaming each table whereever the old one is referenced....

Comment: Then you other option is to set a value in localStorage. If the value does not exist you have to assume you should drop the DB.